# ImageMagick doesn't transform images in portrait (vertical) orientation

Tags: imagemagick, typo3, typoscript

I'm making images transformation in TYPO3, cropping and resizing with **ImageMagick**.

When the orientation is horizontal, all is working fine, when the **image orientation** is **portrait (vertical)**, the system doesn't generate images at all.

There is empty result at the place of generated image link.

Images in landscape (horizontal) orientation generates flawlessly.

TypoScript code, which contains image processing data :

```
...
image {
    file.width = 600c
    file.height = 500c
}
...
```

ImageMagick package info (CentOS 5.7) :

```
Name       : ImageMagick
Arch       : x86_64
Version    : 6.2.8.0
Release    : 4.el5_5.3
```

The same behaviour I saw on Windows 7 installation with ImageMagick 6.7.2

Probably it's related to default ImageMagick configuration ?

Does anybody saw such strange ImageMagick / TYPO3 behavior ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found : the situation was related to the issue of ImageMagick, when the result width size was bigger than default image width.

So, You should use maxW instead width in Your configuration and maxH instead of height.

Example :

```
...
image {
    file.maxW = 600c
    file.maxH = 500c
}
...
```

Comment: On some versions of IM we need to define both types of parameters to make correct transformation to assure the result. So all better to define all parameters : width, height, maxW, maxH.